# Limits and little "oh" notation with trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits

As h approaches 0, show

$$\cos{(x+h)}=\cos{(x)}-h\sin{(x)}+o(h)$$.

I got up to: as h approaches 0

$$\frac{\cos(x)(\cos(h)-1)+\sin(x)(h-\sin(x))}{h}$$

I can't think of what to do from here. I'd like to learn the method using limits as h approaches 0 and differentiation.

Comment: I think that's supposed to say $-h\sin x$.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. You're right.

Comment: How can this be answered using limits as h approaches 0 and differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $$\cos(x+h)=\cos h\cos x-\sin h\sin x$$

Now, incorporate the terms you want, $\cos x-h\sin x$, by adding and subtracting, to get

$$\cos(x+h)=\cos x-h\sin x -\cos x+h\sin x+\cos h\cos x-\sin h\sin x$$

$$\cos(x+h)=\cos x-h\sin x+(\cos h-1)\cos x-\sin x(\sin h-h)$$

It suffices you now use that $$\frac{\cos h-1}h\to 0$$ $$\frac{\sin h-h}h\to 0$$

This shows the last two summands are $o(h)$ as desired.

Comment: How can this be answered using limits as h approaches 0 and differentiation.

Comment: @user117498 I don't understand your question. That's what I did...!

Comment: Oh ok, I've seen this is a solution but don't quite understand it.

Comment: @user117498 What is unclear to you?

Comment: Oh ok, I've seen this is a solution but don't quite understand it. i.e. 

$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos{(x+h)}-\cos{(x)}+h\sin{(x)}}h=0$  
 
$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos{(x+h)}-\cos{(x)}}h+sin{(x)}=0$  

But $\frac{d}{dx}$ ($\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos{(x+h)}-\cos{(x)}}h$)=$\frac{d}{dx} cos(x)$=$-sin(x)$

Therefore, $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos{(x+h)}-\cos{(x)}+h\sin{(x)}}h$=$-sin(x)+sin(x)=0$
   
Therefore, $\cos{(x+h)}=\cos{(x)}-h\sin{(x)}+o(h)$ I don't understand the third line in this provided solution.

Comment: @user117498 Maybe you should make that another question, in a new post, and provide a link to that solution.